# Automatic line-breaking in table with tabularx doesn't work

Tags: tables, line-breaking, tabularx

I followed this post to make the following code:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
         \hline A &  B & C & D & E & F \\ \hline  AA &  BB & CC & blablabla blibli blobloblo blslklqs blablabla blibli blobloblo blslklqs  blablabla blibli blobloblo blslklqs & \cite{urdampilleta2019gate}  \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

However I do not have a line break as one can see below.
[image]

Where is my mistake and how can I fix it ?

Comment: If you're going to use a `tabularx` environment, *at least one column* should have type `X`.

Comment: you are specifying `c` columns they are always single line.

Answer (score 5):

[image: a]

Needs an `X` column. (Also a missing `&` after the `\cite`. It helps aligning the `&` of the rows.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|X|c|c|}
        \hline
            A&B     &C  &D  &E                          &F\\
        \hline
           AA&BB    &CC &blablabla blibli blobloblo blslklqs blablabla blibli blobloblo blslklqs  blablabla blibli blobloblo blslklqs       
                           &\cite{urdampilleta2019gate}&\\
         \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Lose the `\centering` instruction, though, as it's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

For fun and exercise ... by use of the `tabularray` (version 2021N)  package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec={cc c X[j] cc},
                 }
 A  & B & C & D & E & F     \\
AA  &BB &CC & \lipsum[66]
                & \cite{urdampilleta2019gate}
                    &       \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]